# How to Run Multiple iMacros Scripts and Loop with Same Datasource CSV at Once Time

Tags: loops, csv, extract, imacros

I have an iMacros script that is running well. Now, I want to make a copy from that script and edited the script only on the command `URL GOTO` but the Datasource is some file. This is my original script :

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE no
SET !DATASOURCE data.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 20
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO=URL/{{!COL1}}

SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=extractions.csv
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

From that script, I make three copies and edited only on command `URL GOTO`like:

Script 1 `URL GOTO=URLA.com/{{!COL1}}`
Script 2 `URL GOTO=URLB.com/{{!COL1}}`
Script 3 `URL GOTO=URLB.com/{{!COL1}}`

I try this javascript to run and loop those three scripts at once time:

```
var loopcounter = 2

for (i=1;i<=loopcounter;i++){
iimPlay("imacros1.iim")
iimPlay("imacros2.iim")
iimPlay("imacros3.iim")
}
```

That script is running well to run and loop the script but the result is not like I expected. That script is only processing data from first row in Datasource file. In this case I want the script to process all data not only from first row.

Example :

> At first loop imacros1.iim process data1 from row 1, imacros2.iim
>   process data2 from row 2, imacros3.iim process data3 from row 1.
>
> At second loop imacros1.iim process data4 from row 1, imacros2.iim
>   process data5 from row 2, imacros3.iim process data6 from row 1.

Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem? I really appreciate it..
Thanks

Comment: Ouf-ouf..., I hardly understand your Qt/Post as your English is very-very "approx" and your Post is full of Typos and Grammar Mistakes..., I try to improve it a bit, even if it's only for me to try to understand your Post... Control the Content (if my Edit(s) get(s) approved) if it still reflects your original Meaning...  
+ Could you mention your FCI? (Full Config Info), if really using v8.9.6, you should by now be able to answer all iMacros Threads on the Forum actually...! And v8.9.6 is no stable/standard Version to use, for sure in 2018...!  
=> iMacros Version + Browser Version + OS...?

Comment: OK, I did quite a lot of Editing to your OP, ah-ah...!  
+ Removed the 'javascript' and 'extract' Meta-Tags as your Qt/Pb has nothing specific to those 2 Tags..., and MIRACLE...!: I finally understood your Qt, ah-ah...!

Comment: => Yep, you are in some interesting Case of 2D/3D Nested Loops, so OK, ONE DataSource, and 3 different/parallel Macros...
Typical Nested Loops Case, with the extra mini-Difficulty of a (shifted: +1/+2) 'Modulo[3]' for the Looping for each Macro... Yep, why not...
But it still sounds pretty cumbersome to me, as you mentioned that you had to make 2 Copies of your original '.iim', then I don't understand the Need for such a cumbersome Workflow, you could better have one single '.iim' doing all the Looping/Extraction directly...!

Comment: If you posted your URL and the Content of your '!COL1' in your '.CSV', I would very probably find a muuuuuch [Typo intended...!] simpler Solution in pure '.iim' with just one DataSource and just one '.iim' Macro, ah-ah...! No need for 3 '.iim' Macros and 1 '.js' Script, and having to handle 2D/3D Nested Loops, interesting Concept for the "Fun", but you are making your "Life" waaaaay more complicated than it could be, ah-ah...!

Comment: Hum, I've re-added the 'extract' Meta-Tag..., the whole "Logic" of your Workflow actually turns around Extracting..., so yep, that Tag is a bit "Legit" after all...

Comment: Hum, 3 days later and still not Follow-up, I'll stop monitoring this Thread...  
I still didn't really/completely understand your OP about the 'Data[1-6]' part, but OK, the whole "Concept" of the "Scenario" is very cumbersome, I already mentioned... [Good luck anyway..!]

Comment: "not Follow-up" = "no Follow-up"
(5 min to edit a post stupidly too short...)

Comment: I just got back online, I'm so sorry friend for do not follow up to you... Thanks

Comment: Ah OK, 6 days later... Then hum, OK..., and...?, can't you just use one single '.iim' Macro instead of that cumbersome Workflow/Construction of yours...?

Comment: Thanks friend for your responses.., Yeah, i already have a solutions for this problem..

Comment: And one more time if you don't mind.. Is there any command to auto refresh the page in iMacros for command `URL GOTO` if the page not fully loaded? because I already use `SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'` but still not loaded and need to refresh so that can be fully loaded .. Thanks